# Can't set global variable within $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, variables

I am getting some data from a server using `$.getJSON` as follows ..

```
$.getJSON( 'http://192.168.2.24/index.php/hooks/' + a[i].BSSID, function() {
  console.log( "success" );
})
  .done(function(data) {
    url_redirect = data.SSID;
    console.log("DATA:" + url_redirect)
  }) ...
```

Before all of this I declare the variable `url_redirect` but this is not set with `url_redirect = data.SSID` even though the console.log proves it is. If I set `var url_redirect = "";` right at the beginning of my script does this not make it global?

Comment: to make it global, you have to declare it outside any function.

Comment: it is the first line in my script outside of any function

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ — Only in strict mode, which doesn't appear to be being used here. (Although it should be, strict mode is best practise)

Comment: So, it is global, but ajax is asynchronous. So, if you read the variable after you ajax call, it's normal taht you don't have the result => tha jaxa call is not `done`.